# smart way to fill list object by MessageCollection

Tags: c#, list, generics

work on C# .recently i need to fill a List .I has a MessageCollection object .I need to fill this list by this MessageCollection object values.

To fill the list i use the bellow syntax:

```
MessageCollection messages = inbox.SearchParse("SINCE " + currentDate);
List<Message> oMessageList = new List<Message>();

 for (int n = 0; n < messages.Count; n++)
                    {
                       oMessageList .add( messages[n]);
}
```

Above syntax can not satisfy me .Is there any smart way to fill my list?i want to do something like this

```
oMessageList =messages
```

show me error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'ActiveUp.Net.Mail.MessageCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
oMessageList.AddRange(messages);
```

since MessageCollection is derived from CollectionBase, which implements IList.

Comment: above syntax show me The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: cannot convert from 'ActiveUp.Net.Mail.MessageCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ActiveUp.Net.Mail.Message>'

Comment: Try first call MessageCollection.CopyTo() to get an array of message, and then call AddRange(). 

I am not sure if there will be some performance overheads, :)

Comment: David thanks for reply .MessageCollection Has no CopyTo() method

Comment: No CopyTo() method? See this link please:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.messagecollection_members(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thanks again i see your msdn url ,sorry again i fail to understand how to copy will you plz show some clear syntax for me ....